# Remote MySQL database connection using php

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I'm trying to connect to a remote database on a server which is accessed through cPanel.

I created a user name and associated it with a database. I'm using:

I'm confused on the host name to use. I tried using the Main Domain name in the left menu panel in cPanel with the port number 3306 but it wouldn't work. I used the shared IP as well with the port number that that wouldn't work as well. I have added my local machine IP to the remote databases page in the cPanel as was told in a post but finally I'm not able to connect to the database.

On echoing the mysql_error(), I get:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host_name' (4)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you sure the database is listening external? Maybe it's configured to just accept connections from localhost.

Comment: @MarcelBalzer How do I check if database is listening external? I tried
$telnet my_shared_ip:3306
And it gives - **Could not resolve : Name or service unknown**

Comment: And is telnet get a connection?

Comment: telnet is throwing an error
**could not resolve: ip_address:3306/telnet: Name or service not known**

Comment: You don't resolve IP addresses, do you?? You resolve hostnames to ip addresses, and ips get routed, but not resolved. The only case IP addresses get resolved is in mail spam detectors by the reverse DNS.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Even if I try by my hostname, it is not work. I tried either ways.

Comment: If you cannot ping the db either, it might be a network routing problem, or as already said the db is not configured to listen on anything but localhost. Contact your provider :)

Comment: @DanFromGermany: I will contact my provider for more details..

Answer (score 1):

your hosting site will specify which name should be used for the host

in hostinghood.com they says that to use localhost itself as host name

so check what your hosting site says about it

Comment: I don't think a remote connection can be achieved by using localhost as the hostname. It is used for the applications hosted on the same hosting provider. What I'm trying to achieve here is a remote connection to the hosting provider's database.

Comment: i know it but i said that hostinghood.com says to use it for our easyness thay had made the settings like that.if you have any doubt try hosting in hostinghood.com other hosting sites have different name for the host